# Wakeup exception for the kafka connect sink

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Similar kind of issue with kafka-sink for a table from kafka topic

I changed the keys at the sql server end and it gives me below error

> [2019-04-30 15:04:16,946] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc_sink_DDFSC10-0}
>   Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeTriggerWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:487)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:278)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:662)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1425)
>           at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1384)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommitSync(WorkerSinkTask.java:332)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommit(WorkerSinkTask.java:360)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:431)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.closePartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:590)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: This error was not found on google?? any idea??

Comment: I'm getting the same error in an s3 sink, any ideas?